# Airplane Mode doesn't turn off and there is no switch

Tags: wireless, lenovo, airplane-mode

First of all I am new to the site and Ubuntu. I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Z570. Original Os was Win7. Later I had installed Win10. I used to use it with Airplane Mode and WiFi both on. Don't ask me why please. One day OS crashed and thanks to the help of a friend Win7 and Win10 were together installed on the computer. However wireless and Nvidia graphic card didn't work after this installation. I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04. At first during the installation it showed WiFi on and even connected to my home network. Due to a mistake it stopped the installation. In second attempt it was installed successfully but this time airplane mode is on and wifi is not working. There is no physical Airplane-Mode switch on my laptop.

Output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is WiFi switch but it doesn't change anything.

I have googled the issue and tried
`# rfkill unblock all` `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up`

```
*-network DISABLED
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: wlp3s0
            version: 00
            serial: 74:e5:0b:49:bf:12
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:29 memory:f1500000-f1501fff
    *-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
         version: b5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=4096) ioport:f1400000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
            logical name: enp4s0
            version: 05
            serial: f0:de:f1:94:67:6e
            size: 100Mbit/s
            capacity: 100Mbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.0.117 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
            resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1404000-f1404fff memory:f1400000-f1403fff
```

Please tell me if I need to give anymore information to make it clear. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` What does Fn+F5 do? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: Go to BIOS settings and check whether Wi-Fi is enabled from there.

Comment: It is enabled but seems that there is something else blockading it.

Answer (score 0):

On the Lenovo Z570 there is a switch on the front edge of the keyboard that will toggle the hard block as seen in the picture on Lenovo forums https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Z570-I-can-t-turn-on-WiFi/m-p/1434903/highlight/true#M86704

Comment: I know the switch and it is on but doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sounds like the switch is broken, you can either use a piece of tape on pin 20 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzAKcmlaH1M or remove the internal wifi card and use a USB

Comment: Thank you for your comment but switch is physically fine and as i have mentioned in the original post, just today it worked for some time.

Comment: Your question stated "There is no physical Airplane-Mode switch on my laptop."  A physical airplane switch should toggle the rfkill hard block, the FN + F5 will normally only change soft block status

Comment: I thought that it is just wireless hard switch. Has the same symbol with the one on F5. So I assumed that on other computers there is a different switch for airplane. Anyway, no matter what position I put that switch to and use Fn+F5 neither soft block nor the hard block status doesn't change.

Comment: Might be such a thing as that that laptop blocks wifi when an ethernet cable is plugged in

Comment: I have removed Ethernet cable and tried to turn on wifi. Both with hard and soft keys. However it doesn't help. I tried to search for wifi networks but dialog opens and says that airplane mode is on and should go to wireless settings. When I go to wifi settings I get "No wifi adapter found" message.

Comment: post URL for `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: https://termbin.com/yvc6

Comment: Run the 2 commands @ https://gist.github.com/jeremyb31/a2bee9856d8c13f42f1835bc31bf9480 in terminal and post URL

Comment: https://termbin.com/p961

Comment: you could try `echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad_laptop.conf` and reboot but I don't think it will work because you model has the physical switch

Comment: Yes, it din't work. Thanks anyway for your time. I'm grateful.